# How to unnest and display elements of a JSON array?

Tags: postgresql, json

i have this table :

[image]

And i want display all the names in the table like this :

[image]

Also i want to list the number of gender each genre : Desired output:

[image]

Comment: Please post [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852/) as [**formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), [not as  screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-json.html), the `#>` operator comes in useful:

```sql
-- name and genre of people (1 row per person)
select
    json_array_elements(
      t.test#>'{clients, info}'
        )::json
    ->>'nom' as nom,
    json_array_elements(
      t.test#>'{clients, info}'
        )::json
    ->>'genre' as genre
from my_table t
```

```
-- number of people, grouped by gender (1 row per gender)
select
      json_array_elements(
         t.test#>'{clients, info}'
           )::json
           ->>'genre' as genre,
      count (t.*) as count
from my_table t
group by 1
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7ec38/2)

Comment: THank u uu for your response but i have an error :  ERROR:  ERREUR:  ne peut pas appeler json_array_elements sur un type non tableau


SQL state: 22023

Comment: Odd ; I made a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7ec38/2) for easier editing. Maybe try adding some parentheses around `t.test#>'{clients, info}')::json` ?